# Copy a file only to the first subdirectory

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, subdirectory

I want to copy a file to the first subdirectory of a folder.

Example:

```
\---main_folder
    |
    \---subfolder *(copy here)*
        |
        \---sub_subfolder *(do NOT copy here)*
```

I know it is quite easy to copy a file to a directory and it's subdirectories, e.g:

```
for /r "G:\main_folder" %%i in (.) do @copy "G:\abc.txt" "%%i"
```

But this code copies the file to ALL subdirectories of `main_folder`, whereas I wish only to copy to `subfolder` *(See my rudimentary example)*.

I checked the help on `for`, *(`for /?`)*, but couldn't figure this out.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try with `for /D %%I in ("G:\main_folder\*") do @copy "G:\abc.txt" "%%~I"`; since you are using `for /R`, your file is copied into the whole directory tree, but `for /D` stays at one tree level...

Comment: That did it, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using [`for /R`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html), your file is going to be copied into every directory in your tree.

Use [`for /D`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) instead to iterate throufgh a certain hierarchy level, like in the following example:

```cmd
for /D %%I in ("G:\main_folder\*") do copy "G:\abc.txt" "%%~I"
```

This of course copies the file into every immediate sub-directory of `G:\main_folder`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your question asks, `'I want to copy a file to the first subdirectory of a folder.'`, and not, `'I want to copy a file to every top level subdirectory of a folder.'`, *which is what the comment, you've agreed works does*. You need to first decide on what constitutes `first`.

This example uses `first` as that which is determined by name sort order *(alphabetically)*.

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir /B/AD/ON "G:\main_folder"') Do @Copy /Y "G:\abc.txt" "%%A" & GoTo :EOF
```

**Edit**
Because you've now clarified that your question parameters were wrong, *not misinterpreted*, i.e.  `'I want to copy a file to every top level subdirectory of a folder'` then the comment initially provided showed a correct method:

```bat
@For /D %%A In ("G:\main_folder\*") Do @If Exist "G:\abc.txt" Copy /Y "G:\abc.txt" "%%A" >Nul 2>&1
```

Alternatively, *should be fractionally quicker*, performing the `If Exist` first:

```bat
@If Exist "G:\abc.txt" For /D %%A In ("G:\main_folder\*") Do @Copy /Y "G:\abc.txt" "%%A" >Nul 2>&1
```

Comment: Yes, i meant `every top level subdirectory`.

In hindsight, I agree that the original question can be misinterpreted.

Thanks for the alternative solution!

Comment: @Compo did you have specific reason to not place the `If Exist` condition behind the loop?

Comment: @sst, I placed the `If Exist` within the `For` loop, I could have also made the `For` loop dependent upon the existence thus: `@If Exist "G:\abc.txt" For /D %%A In ("G:\main_folder\*") Do @Copy /Y "G:\abc.txt" "%%A" >Nul 2>&1` and have accordingly included that in my **Edit**.